# Magento 2 : Product grid serializer issue

Tags: magento2, ajax, product-grid

Inserted a product grid in my custom admin form using the below code:
**UPDATED**
view/adminhtml/layout/mymodule_form.xml

```
<fieldset name="assign_products">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="assign_products_container" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Company\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Productgrid\AssignProducts</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

Company/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Productgrid/AssignProducts.php

```
namespace Company\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Productgrid;

class AssignProducts extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    /**
     * Block template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'mymodule/category/edit/assign_products.phtml';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
     */
    protected $blockGrid;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface
     */
    protected $jsonEncoder;

    /**
     * AssignProducts constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve instance of grid block
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getBlockGrid()
    {

        if (null === $this->blockGrid) {
            $this->blockGrid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Company\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Mymodule\Tab\Product',
                'category.product.grid'
            );
        }
        return $this->blockGrid;
    }

    /**
     * Return HTML of grid block
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridHtml()
    {

        return $this->getBlockGrid()->toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductsJson()
    {
        $products = $this->getCategory()->getProductsPosition();
        if (!empty($products)) {
            return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($products);
        }
        return '{}';
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve current category instance
     *
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('mymodule_item');
    }
}
```

Company/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Mymodule/Tab/Product.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Product in category grid
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
namespace Company\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Mymodule\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;

class Product extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Productlabel\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('catalog_category_products');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('mymodule_item');
    }

    /**
     * @param Column $column
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        // Set custom filter for in category flag
        if ($column->getId() == 'in_category') {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
            } elseif (!empty($productIds)) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $productIds]);
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        if ($this->getCategory()->getId()) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_category' => 1]);
        }
        $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'sku'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'price'
        )->joinField(
            'position',
            'catalog_category_product',
            'position',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            'category_id=' . (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0),
            'left'
        );
        $storeId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        if ($storeId > 0) {
            $collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);
        }
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        if ($this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
        }

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        if (!$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'in_category',
                [
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'name' => 'in_category',
                    'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                    'index' => 'entity_id',
                    'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                    'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
                ]
            );
        }
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('name', ['header' => __('Name'), 'index' => 'name']);
        $this->addColumn('sku', ['header' => __('SKU'), 'index' => 'sku']);
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency_code' => (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                ),
                'index' => 'price'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'position',
            [
                'header' => __('Position'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'position',
                'editable' => !$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('catalog/category/grid', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_products');
        if ($products === null) {
            $products = $this->getCategory()->getProductsPosition();
            return array_keys($products);
        }
        return $products;
    }
}
```

web/templates/mymodule/category/edit/assign_products.phtml

```
$blockGrid = $block->getBlockGrid();
$gridJsObjectName = $blockGrid->getJsObjectName();
?>
<?php  echo $block->getGridHtml(); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="category_products" id="in_category_products" data-form-part="mymodule_form" value="" />
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Company_Mymodule/mymodule/category/assign-products": {
                "selectedProducts": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductsJson(); ?>,
                "gridJsObjectName": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo '"' . $gridJsObjectName . '"' ?: '{}'; ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- @todo remove when "UI components" will support such initialization -->
<script>
    require('mage/apply/main').apply();
</script>
```

assign-products.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/* global $, $H */

define([
    'mage/adminhtml/grid'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {
        var selectedProducts = config.selectedProducts,
            categoryProducts = $H(selectedProducts),
            gridJsObject = window[config.gridJsObjectName],
            tabIndex = 1000;

        $('in_category_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);

        /**
         * Register Category Product
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {Object} element
         * @param {Boolean} checked
         */
        function registerCategoryProduct(grid, element, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = false;
                    categoryProducts.set(element.value, element.positionElement.value);
                }
            } else {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = true;
                }
                categoryProducts.unset(element.value);
            }
            $('in_category_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
            grid.reloadParams = {
                'selected_products[]': categoryProducts.keys()
            };
        }

        /**
         * Click on product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function categoryProductRowClick(grid, event) {
            var trElement = Event.findElement(event, 'tr'),
                isInput = Event.element(event).tagName === 'INPUT',
                checked = false,
                checkbox = null;

            if (trElement) {
                checkbox = Element.getElementsBySelector(trElement, 'input');

                if (checkbox[0]) {
                    checked = isInput ? checkbox[0].checked : !checkbox[0].checked;
                    gridJsObject.setCheckboxChecked(checkbox[0], checked);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Change product position
         *
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function positionChange(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);

            if (element && element.checkboxElement && element.checkboxElement.checked) {
                categoryProducts.set(element.checkboxElement.value, element.value);
                $('in_category_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Initialize category product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} row
         */
        function categoryProductRowInit(grid, row) {
            var checkbox = $(row).getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0],
                position = $(row).getElementsByClassName('input-text')[0];

            if (checkbox && position) {
                checkbox.positionElement = position;
                position.checkboxElement = checkbox;
                position.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
                position.tabIndex = tabIndex++;
                Event.observe(position, 'keyup', positionChange);
            }
        }

        gridJsObject.rowClickCallback = categoryProductRowClick;
        gridJsObject.initRowCallback = categoryProductRowInit;
        gridJsObject.checkboxCheckCallback = registerCategoryProduct;

        if (gridJsObject.rows) {
            gridJsObject.rows.each(function (row) {
                categoryProductRowInit(gridJsObject, row);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Now the product grid appears on my form, but the issue is no product ids are getting on post values.Moreover the ajax actions are also not working.{I don't want to show position field in product grid compared to the default product grid in category form}

Please help me, Iam struggling with this product grid.:(

Comment: what is the path of assign-products.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your assign-products.js

```
define([
    'mage/adminhtml/grid'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {
        var selectedProducts = config.selectedProducts,
            categoryProducts = $H(selectedProducts),
            gridJsObject = window[config.gridJsObjectName],
            tabIndex = 1000;

        $('in_category_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);

        /**
         * Register Category Product
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {Object} element
         * @param {Boolean} checked
         */
        function registerCategoryProduct(grid, element, checked) {
            if (checked) {

                 categoryProducts.set(element.value, '');
            } else {                
                categoryProducts.unset(element.value);
            }
            $('in_category_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
            grid.reloadParams = {
                'selected_products[]': categoryProducts.keys()
            };
        }

        /**
         * Click on product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function categoryProductRowClick(grid, event) {
            var trElement = Event.findElement(event, 'tr'),
                isInput = Event.element(event).tagName === 'INPUT',
                checked = false,
                checkbox = null;

            if (trElement) {
                checkbox = Element.getElementsBySelector(trElement, 'input');

                if (checkbox[0]) {
                    checked = isInput ? checkbox[0].checked : !checkbox[0].checked;
                    gridJsObject.setCheckboxChecked(checkbox[0], checked);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Change product position
         *
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function positionChange(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);

            if (element && element.checkboxElement && element.checkboxElement.checked) {
                categoryProducts.set(element.checkboxElement.value, element.value);
                $('in_category_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Initialize category product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} row
         */
        function categoryProductRowInit(grid, row) {
            var checkbox = $(row).getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0];             
        }

        gridJsObject.rowClickCallback = categoryProductRowClick;
        gridJsObject.initRowCallback = categoryProductRowInit;
        gridJsObject.checkboxCheckCallback = registerCategoryProduct;

        if (gridJsObject.rows) {
            gridJsObject.rows.each(function (row) {
                categoryProductRowInit(gridJsObject, row);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then remove position field from Company/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Mymodule/Tab/Product.php

Comment: I am getting error like "Cannot set property 'value' of null" at $('in_category_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts); when initially no values are selected.

Answer (score 4):

you have to add this getProductsPosition method in your model .i had same issue then i customize below code

```
 public function getProductsPosition()
{
    if (!$this->getId()) {
        return [];
    }
    $array = $this->getData('products_position');
    if ($array === null) {
        $temp = $this->getData('product_id');

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->getData('product_id')); $i++) {
            $array[$temp[$i]] = 0;
        }
        $this->setData('products_position', $array);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: dont remove position field from products grid because after removing it serializer will not work

Comment: But when i add position field in my custom form , getting an error :"Call to a member function getProductsReadonly() on null in /Company/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Productgrid/Tab/Product.php on line 170"

Comment: have you register mymodule_item in edit form ?

Comment: $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('mymodule_item', $model);

Comment: In my Company\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Mymodule\Edit\Button\Generic 
 "   public function getRequest()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('mymodule_item');
    }"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50088/discussion-between-ashar-riaz-and-e-b).

Comment: from where you are calling this method getProductsReadonly(

Comment: I have saved the selected product ids into  db as comma separated values, but now I need to show the selected products when I go for editing the form. Please Help.